# web3.isConnected() returns nothing when connecting to geth with web3.js(Version 0.19.0)

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, testrpc, nodejs

> web3.isConnected() has issue. When connecting to an IPC node

I think it is waiting for something because when i starting my nodejs program nothing happens,

I am running ethereum node and try to connect with my Dapp 
But there is some problem with my rpc connection that is `web3.isConnected()` is not returning anything 
 It should return true or false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> web3.isConnected() has issue. When connecting to an IPC node, it will
>   always hang up if that IPC node is up and running but PORT is not OPEN

Answer (score 2):

If you have MetaMask installed and using it, select custom RPC and put http://localhost:4000.

In case of MetaMask, call new Web3 instance, web3js(or anything else), as web3 is already defined.

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') 
{
    web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
}
else {
    web3js = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:4000'));
}
```